# android studio get Activity object from service

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

i have an app with service that works completely background, but sometimes i need to change the content in the foreground activity , for now let's say  i want to show `Toast`.

 

first i am checking if the app is opened as foreground

```
 public boolean isForeground(String myPackage) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> runningTaskInfo = manager.getRunningTasks(1);
    ComponentName componentInfo = runningTaskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
    return componentInfo.getPackageName().equals(myPackage);
}
```

then i want to know what is the running activity

```
  String PKG_Name = componentInfo.getPackageName();
```

this will give me the name , but what i want is to is get the object `Activity` ,to do something like this:

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

how can i do it? if not possible, is there's a way to is to send a signal or a message to the service to  tell the it?

Answer (score 0):

For that you have two options, if you are fine showing just a Toast and not interact with other elements, you can implement a broadcast reciever and make your custom intent with custom action,
`Intent int= new Intent();   int.setAction("Your custom string here");`
and then post a toast in your braodcast reciever,

OR

you can use a custom handler to interact with all the objects in foreground and activity, here's some study material for it,
https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui